# typescript, Communication between components

Tags: angular, rest, http, typescript

I Using Library.
"Angular 4.x, DataTable, Typescript"

Can not use http when calling functions from other components ?

I have to use. Is there a way?
Help Me Please ...

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You probably just need to inject `http` service. But please, post the code as text and if possible, make a plnkr example so that the the issue can be re-produced.

Comment: you can simply add code instead of pictures. i was unable see picture clearly.

Comment: I add picture.. Please look again

Comment: Where do you call `appDownload()`?

Comment: DataTable.ts - Line 98
< let download = this.appDownload; >

and

DataTable.ts - Line 114
Button Click Event Call download()

Comment: No what I meant is where do you try to call the method in Market.ts line 120 ?

Comment: Never add your code as pictures, what if someone wants to debug your code? No one is gonna type all that code long hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please import​ `HttpModule` in app.module.ts

Comment: I add picture.. 
Please look again

Comment: Actually issue here is it is not able to determine `this` keyword.
Can you try one thing instead of passing download to your jQuery callback  assign this to some variable before call like

     `let x = this;`

and then try something like this in your callback 

    `x.appDownload(....);`